# how to fire method with every ajax request with @ViewScoped

Tags: jsf

I use JSF 2.2 and i have to invoke method with every ajax request i used @PostConstruct in @Named @viewScoped but it fires when i call bean first time but doesn't fire after that because i use @ViewScoped so can you give me way to invoke method with every ajax request

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;


@Named(value = "branchesMB")
@ViewScoped
public class BranchesController extends CRUDController<Branches> implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private BranchesFacade branchesFacade;
    private List<String> jsfMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of BranchesController
     */
    public BranchesController() {
        setEntityObject(new Branches());
        setEntityEditObject(new Branches());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        JsfUtil.resetValidationError(true, "branchesAddForm:branchNameDiv");
        JsfUtil.resetValidationError(true, "branchesAddForm:branchAddressDiv");
        JsfUtil.resetValidationError(true, "branchesAddForm:branchAbbreviationDiv");
        JsfUtil.hideAlertMessage("branchesForm:messages");
        JsfUtil.hideAlertMessage("branchesAddForm:messages");

//        System.out.println("koko");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use requestScoped then?

Comment: because when i use delete method will delete another row it 2 users delete something at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method with CompositeSystemEvent as input parameter and define that method inside event tag on your xhtml with type "preRenderView", like below:

On backing bean:

```
 public void onPageLoad(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Here");
    }
```

On xhtml page:

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.onPageLoad}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
```

This method will get called each time before a full page load and on every ajax call.

Comment: i want to call this method at first the approach called this method at the end

Comment: From your called ajax method simply call post construct at first line.